# STM32 RNG Clocking Error

Tags: random, embedded, clock, stm32

I'm beginner in embedded developent, and I'm using board STM32F417VGx

There are troubles with getting RNG to work
I tried to do it either with wrighting values directly to registers and with CMSIS Peripheral Libraty fuctions.

So, my code:

```
int main() {
    SystemInit();              /* Initialize clocks */
    Init_GPIO();               /* Initialize LED's pins */
    Init_RNG();                /* Initialize RNG */

    RCC_ClocksTypeDef clocks;  
    RCC_GetClocksFreq(&clocks); /* Check clocks */
                                /* All clocks are 16 MHz (F42400) */

    while(1) {
        unsigned rdiode = randomRange(0, 3);
        toggleDiode(GPIOD, DIODES[rdiode]);
        soft_delay(1000000);
    }

}
```

InitRNG():

```
void Init_RNG() {
    RCC_AHB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB2Periph_RNG, ENABLE);
    RNG_Cmd(ENABLE);
}
```

randomRange(uint, uint):

```
uint32_t randomRange(uint32_t low, uint32_t int high){
    while(RNG_GetFlagStatus(RNG_FLAG_DRDY) == RESET);
    return RNG_GetRandomNumber() % (high-low) + low;
}
```

And it hangs on while(RNG_GetFlagStatus(RNG_FLAG_DRDY) == RESET);
CEIS in RNG_SR is 0x1, so there is clocking error.

I'd looked everywhere in google, in every tutorial RNG works out-of-box, nobody even cares about checking SEIS and CEIS flags (?_?)
So I know that RNG needs at least 48MHz clock, but I can't find out what clocking source it uses and how to ajust it's clock :C

In stm32f4xx.h I have those clocking values (was recommended in one tutorial), but HSE is external (not on-board) clocking source, isn't it?

```
#define HSE_VALUE    ((uint32_t)8000000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine.

RNG is clocked by AHB2. This clock is derived from SYSCLK divided by the AHB prescaler (HPRE in RCC_CFGR). It is also called HCLK. But as the reference manual says:

> The RNG_LFSR is clocked by a dedicated clock (RNG_CLK) at a constant
>   frequency, so that the quality of the random number is independent of the HCLK frequency.

Check the value of RNG_SR. If any of the SEIS, CEIS, SECS, CECS flags is set you will be stuck in an endless loop. Check the correct clocking of your MCU. Do you use an external (HSE) or the internal clock (HSI)?